# deleting specific strings python

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following in a python 3 numpy.ndarray:

```
{"_id" : "123", "text" : "some writing"}
{"_id" : "456", "text" : "some more writing"}
{"_id" : "789", "text" : "some more more writing"}
```

Question:
How do I delete `{"_id" :` and `"text" :` to get the following:

```
{"123", "some writing"}
{"456", "some more writing"}
{"789", "some more more writing"}
```

Comment: Your formatting suggests you have dicts, not NumPy arrays. Perhaps you store dicts as objects in a NumPy array, which is rather inefficient. You'll have to show the code how you create your arrays for people to understand what your actual data structure is.

Comment: Furthermore: what have you already tried, and with what results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following was:

```
arr = [{"_id" : "123", "text" : "some writing"}, {"_id" : "456", "text" : "some more writing"}, {"_id" : "789", "text" : "some more more writing"}]
ans = [{i['_id']: i['text']}for i in arr]
```